# SQL server error - string or binary data would be truncated - even though SELECT statement returns nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query in my stoted procedure, something like,

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    (UniqueStr, Col1, Col2)
SELECT UniqueStr, Col1, Col2
    FROM Table2
WHERE ...
```

It gives me error:

> string or binary data would be truncated.

Here are the statistics.

1. `Table1.UniqueStr` is `VARCHAR(11)`
2. `Table2.UniqueStr` is `VARCHAR(20)`
3. `Table2` has records having `UniqueStr` values of 11 characters and 15 characters.
4. The where clause of query is written in such a way that `SELECT` statement will never return records having `UniqueStr` length greater than 11.

The first weird scenario is - even though `SELECT` statement returns nothing (when run separately), it gives truncation error when run along with `INSERT` (i.e. INSERT...SELECT).

Second weird scenario is - it gives error only in Production environment. It gave no error in `UAT` environment. In Production environment, it ran fine for 1 day.

can anyone tell me what could be the issue?

Note: I fixed this error using `SUBSTRING` function but I could not find out the reason why SQL server gives this error?

Comment: Did you check for triggers?

Comment: Are those the column sizes for table 2,or the largest values held in practice.

Comment: Always cast or truncate strings to destination column width - SQL server may evaluate such conditions *before* evaluating where clause.

Comment: 1. If there are records in Table2 as you have said how come no records when you run select statement separately? Do you filter our records in where statement?
2. What are col1 and col2 types? Are they varchar? May be those fields are causing this issue?

Comment: destination-data --> Yes, large values held in practice.

Sam --> This is one of the scenario where though SELECT stmt doesn't return any data (due to WHERE clause filter), it still gives error. 
Yes, I filter records in WHERE clause. Filter in such a way that it will never return records having UniqueStr length greater than 11.
Col1 and Col2 not giving error. I confirmed it in my query. I put it here just for illustration purpose.

Comment: There is a logical processing order for queries. Databases are free to rearrange the *actual* processing order, provided they produce results consistent with the logical order. Unfortunately, SQL Server does the first bit (rearranging the actual processing order) without doing the second (produce results consistent with the logical order). So whilst *logically* the `WHERE` is processed before the `SELECT` and `INSERT`, that won't necessarily stop SQL Server from generating errors caused by processing data that *should* be filtered by the `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks  Damien_The_Unbeliever, I presumed this. There must be something wrong happening while parsing the query but I don't see any proof or documentation. Moreover, I could not find any precise circumstances which will cause the issue. So my real concern is - how can I find out such scenarios in my product (my product is much larger having thousands of procedures.).

Comment: No, it's not a parsing issue. It's just that the optimizer has produced a plan where it aggressively performs conversions before they're strictly necessary. Unfortunately, the [issue is well known](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) but there's been no feedback from MS about it for years and no signs that they plan to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever - this is what I was looking for, some documentation or link explaining this behavior. If you can put as Answer,I will mark it as Answer.